# Как сделать так чтобы в листе прописывалась связь с текущим элементом?

Tags: java, hibernate

Такой вопрос.
Имеется 2 сущности: А и В, связь у них 1 ко многим (аннотации пропускаю)

```
class A{
  List<B> bList;
}

class B{
  A a;
}
```

На вход мне попадается дтошка класса `А`, при переводе из дто в ентити в классе `А` в лист `bList` в элементе ссылке на `а` попадает `null`, как сделать так чтобы при сохранении `А` с листом `bList` чтобы в каждом элементе листа поля `а` была добавлена ссылка на текущий класс `А`?

Сейчас я это делаю вот так, что по мне выглядит очень плохо:

```
А a = fromDtoToEntity(a,aDto);
a.getBList().foreach(s->s.setA(a));
```

Comment: В случае двунаправленной связи других вариантов особо то и нет, кроме как прописывать всё вручную. Можно поиграться с однонаправленной связью (тогда у зависимого класса `B` не надо будет прописывать зависимости), но это влечёт за собой массу других проблем.

Comment: @Serodv расстроили вы меня

Answer (score 0):

Нужно гдето в A прописать присвоение ссылки, в конструктори и\или в сеттере

```
class A
{
...
  setBList(List<B> bList)
  {
    bList.foreach(s->s.setA(this))
    this.bList = blList;
  }
}
```

тогда ссылки будут правильными сразу при создании объекта

Comment: я как раз так и сделал, по мне тоже не очень

Comment: Других вариантов особо то и нет. Если м создаем новые объекты из дтошки, вызвав метод save() оно должно само все заполнить, даже если мы никаких сылок не присваивали явно

Comment: этот вариант мне не подходит, так как теряется ссылка с базы и я не смогу сделать orphanRemoval=true, кинет ексепшн что типо связанных объектов нет, хотя они есть)